# Can I test Linkedin's fullprofile permissions and fields in development cycle?

Tags: linkedin-api

Linkedin has a whole slew of fields to pull them with their API. But they say they want you to apply for something before you can request the fields (see a screenshot below). My question is, can I query those fields during development to test my app? Now Linkein returns error, if I try to request them. And Linkedin doesn't say anything about it in their API docs.

> InternalOAuthError: Failed to obtain request token

Here is a screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know the answer whether I can test the behavior during development.

However, with trial and error method I found what permissions generate error in Linkedin. Lol thing is that you can request fields from those permissions just fine (no error throws), but cannot request permissions.

Fields from forbidden permissions (do not throw even if permissions are omitted in a request):

```
['languages', 'date-of-birth', 'phone-numbers', 'im-accounts'],
```

Forbidden permissions that throw:

```
['r_fullprofile', 'r_contactinfo'],
```